# how to add a .aidl file in a delphi android project?

Tags: java, delphi, aidl, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have two .aidl files and I need to add them to a project delphi.
IPrinterCallback.aidl
IPrinterService.aidl

```
    // IPrinterService.aidl
    package com.xcheng.printerservice;
    import com.xcheng.printerservice.IPrinterCallback;
    //import java.util.List;
    //import java.util.Map;

    // Declare any non-default types here with import statements

    interface IPrinterService {
     /**
     * Demonstrates some basic types that you can use as parameters
     * and return values in AIDL.
     */
...
...
```

The idea is simply to create a button to click and print anything using these packages.
I read several tutorials and got nothing so far.
In one of them I saw that I needed to generate the equivalent .java files and add them to the project.

```
/*
 * This file is auto-generated.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 */
package com.xcheng.printerservice;
//import java.util.List;
//import java.util.Map;
// Declare any non-default types here with import statements

public interface IPrinterService extends android.os.IInterface
{
  /** Default implementation for IPrinterService. */
  public static class Default implements com.xcheng.printerservice.IPrinterService
  {
    /**
         * Demonstrates some basic types that you can use as parameters
         * and return values in AIDL.
         */
    @Override public void upgradePrinter() throws android.os.RemoteException
    {
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

So I generated them using aidl.exe from skd android and put them in a folder inside the project.
But I always get a compilation error when I try to import it in 'uses'.

my code without importing the AIDL

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.Os,
  Android.ServiceApplication,
  FMX.Helpers.Android;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Print: TButton;
    private
      { Private declarations }
    public
      { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```

```
    MyProject/
    |
    +-- src/
    |   |
    |   +-- com/
    |       |
    |       +-- xcheng/
    |           |
    |           +-- printerservice/
    |               |
    |               +-- IPrinterService.aidl
    |               +-- IPrinterCallback.aidl
    |               +-- IPrinterService.java
    |               +-- IPrinterCallback.java
    |
    +-- assets/
    |
    +-- AndroidManifest.xml
    +-- MyProject.dproj
    ...
    ...
```

Can anyone help me import and consume these files .aidl or .java in android delphi?

Comment: You cannot directly use java nor aidl files in Delphi. You need to build JAR from those files and then you can use them. For the last part (using JAR in Delphi) see https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_a_Custom_Set_of_Java_Libraries_In_Your_RAD_Studio_Android_Apps

Comment: I tried following this tutorial but even generating the file with java2op.exe and including it in the project in the uses directive it does not find the classes.